# How go to next tabindex when Enter key pressed in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have some form which include some textbox and their tabindex is not default. I want when user pressed enter key they can select next tabindex but any solution i find it seems only work with default tabindex not custom.

This is my page :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input").not($(":button")).keypress(function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
      iname = $(this).val();
      if (iname !== 'Submit') {
        var fields = $(this).parents('form:eq(0),body').find('button,input,textarea,select');
        var index = fields.index(this);
        if (index > -1 && (index + 1) < fields.length) {
          fields.eq(index + 1).focus();
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <br />
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
  <br />
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TabIndex="3"></asp:TextBox>
  <br />
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>
  <br />
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" TabIndex="5"></asp:TextBox>
  <br />
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" TabIndex="4"></asp:TextBox>
  <br />
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" TabIndex="6" Text="Button" />
</div>
```

The jquery code which i find in web work fine if i use default tabindex but my textbox tabindex is not default as u see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.index get the index of elements in sequence and not the tabIndex attribute. Try this:
https://api.jquery.com/index/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input").not($(":submit, :button")).keypress(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
       var next = $('[tabindex="'+(this.tabIndex+1)+'"]');
       if(next.length )
        next.focus()
       else
         $('[tabindex="1"]').focus();  
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="test"> 
<div>
 <br />
  <input ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TabIndex="1">
  <br />
 <input ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TabIndex="3">
  <br />
<input ID="TextBox3" runat="server" TabIndex="2">
  <br />
<input ID="TextBox4" runat="server" TabIndex="5">
  <br />
 <input ID="TextBox5" runat="server" TabIndex="4">
  <br />
 <input type="submit" runat="server" TabIndex="6" Text="Button" value="Submit">
  <input type="button" runat="server" TabIndex="7" Text="Button" value="Cancel">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you @Marcos , I checked and it worked almost good but i had to set UseSubmitBehavior="false" for my button otherwise everytime i click enter my submit button triggered. it seems "if (iname !== 'Submit') {" not working.

Comment: Enter is a default event to form submit. You can also "cancel" this default with the command: evt.preventDefault(); I updated the example, take a look.

Comment: Thank you @Marcos you solve my biggest problem and i used your code and add some more code (copy code from some where else) and now it's work like a charm, again thank you and i couldn't solve this problem without your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Marcos for main javascript code, i add some code and it's work like a charm now, enter will change the focus to next one until it get on a button, when you press button it will trigger the button code behind (not next focus).

```js
    function stopRKey(evt) {
        var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
        var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
        if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type == "text")) { return false; } else { fuNextFocus() }
    }
    document.onkeypress = stopRKey;


    function fuNextFocus ()
    {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input").not($(":button")).keypress(function (evt) {
                if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
                    iname = $(this).val();
                    //Submit
                    if (iname !== 'Button') {
                        var next = $('[tabindex="' + (this.tabIndex + 1) + '"]');
                        if (next.length)
                            next.focus()
                        else
                            $('[tabindex="1"]').focus();
                    }

                }
            });
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="test"> 
<div>
 <br />
  <input ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TabIndex="1">
  <br />
 <input ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TabIndex="3">
  <br />
<input ID="TextBox3" runat="server" TabIndex="2">
  <br />
<input ID="TextBox4" runat="server" TabIndex="5">
  <br />
 <input ID="TextBox5" runat="server" TabIndex="4">
  <br />
 <input type="submit" runat="server" TabIndex="6" Text="Button" value="Submit">
  <input type="button" runat="server" TabIndex="7" Text="Button" value="Cancel">
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this because of tabIndex not being sequential by 1.  I have a page where it was increments of 10 and 100 to leave space for future additions.

```js
function findNextElement(senderElement) {
  var focussableElements = 'a:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), input[type=text]:not([disabled]), [tabindex]:not([disabled]):not([tabindex="-1"])';
  if (senderElement && senderElement.form) {
    var focussable = Array.prototype.filter.call(senderElement.form.querySelectorAll(focussableElements), function(element) {
       return element.offsetWidth > 0 || element.offsetHeight > 0 || element === senderElement
    });
    // make a duplicate
    var inputs_original =  Array.prototype.filter.call(senderElement.form.querySelectorAll(focussableElements), function(element) {
       return element.offsetWidth > 0 || element.offsetHeight > 0 || element === senderElement
    });;

    // sort by tabIndex
    focussable.sort(function(a, b) {
      if ($(a)[0].tabIndex == $(b)[0].tabIndex) {
         // If tabindex is equal - sort by the position in the DOM
         if (inputs_original.indexOf(a) < inputs_original.indexOf(b))          {
            return -1;
         } else {
            return 1;
         }
      } else if ($(a)[0].tabIndex < $(b)[0].tabIndex) {
         return -1;
      } else {
         return 1;
      }
    });

    var index = focussable.indexOf(senderElement);
    return focussable[index + 1];
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function stopRKey(evt) {
    var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
    var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
    if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type == "text")) { return false; } else { fuNextFocus() }
}
document.onkeypress = stopRKey;

function fuNextFocus () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input").not($(":button")).keypress(function (evt) {
                if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
                    iname = $(this).val();
                    //Submit
                    if (iname !== 'Button') {
                        var next = $('[tabindex="' + (this.tabIndex + 1) + '"]');
                        if (next.length)
                            next.focus()
                        else
                            $('[tabindex="1"]').focus();
                    }

                }
            });
        });
}
```